# Show value in Expandble List

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i am working on an expandable list view.but i am getting an error "Cannot instantiate the type ExpandableListAdapter".
my code is---

```
public class Calculator_new_Pop extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;

public Calculator_new_Pop(Activity parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(parent);
        this._act = parent;}


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(_act, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

//      
}}
```

can any one help me out???

Answer (score 0):

Chanege this

```
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(_act, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

with

```
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this); 
listAdapter (_act, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

OR

```
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(ActivityName.this);
listAdapter (_act, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

If you want to continue with your code,initialize _act with `_act=new Activity(context);`